# SQL Full Trim Function - Access/VBA code I can do it, but I don't know SQL Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, ms-access, trim

I need to combine fields and then trim out extra spaces the middle of a text field.  With Access it's easy for me but creating a SQL Function eludes me.  This is how I do it in Access, anyone able to help me create a SQL Function?

In VBA Access Query I can do this with the following code in query:

```
FullTrim([tblLeadsResi].[House Number] & [tblLeadsResi].[Street] & " " & 
    [tblLeadsResi].[Street Suffix] & " " & [tblLeadsResi].[Post-directional] & 
    IIf(Not IsNull([tblLeadsResi].[Apartment Number])," #" & 
    [tblLeadsResi].[Apartment Number],""))
```

Module Code in Access: (Basically if it's a double space it doesn't add the first space back in)

```
Public Function FullTrim(stText As String) As Variant
Dim intLen As Integer, stPart As String, stBlank As String, stNewText As String

    '   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    '   ++++    Takes any spaces away from a Text Value     ++++
    '   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    If IsNull(stText) Or stText = "" Then
        FullTrim = ""
    Else
        For intLen = 1 To (Len(stText) - 1)
            stPart = Mid(stText, intLen, 1)
            stBlank = Mid(stText, intLen, 2)
            If stBlank <> "  " Then
                stNewText = stNewText & stPart
            End If
        Next intLen

        intLen = Len(stText)
        stPart = Mid(stText, intLen, 1)
        stNewText = stNewText & stPart

        stNewText = Trim(stNewText)
        FullTrim = stNewText
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The Issue is I have to add spaces to the data to merge fields together, but some of the fields are blank.  I'm actually corrupting the data to merge the fields because I don't always have a street suffix or directional data.  

I'm trying to clean up the data by merging several fields into one (I purchase Leads and they come this way)

Comment: SQL does not mean SQL Server. Oracle and Access, amongst a number of other databases, all have their own version of SQL. If you want an SQL Server answer, please use an SQL server tag, not a generic SQL tag.

Comment: A) Sorry I added the General SQL Tag as well as SQL-Server tag; I am new to this web site.
B) I am new to SQL-Server as well if you'd like to give me an example of how to concatenate it better I would appreciate it.
C) The provided information will help me with future data imports the reason I have the Full Trim in Access in the first place was I get Leads data from many sources and have to clean their data up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creation**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FullTrim(@Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Subs NVARCHAR(6)
    SET @Subs = '~@$$#%' -- Make this some string you will never have in your data
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Value, '  ', ' ' + @Subs), @Subs + ' ', ''), @Subs, '')))
END
```

**Usage**

```
SELECT dbo.FullTrim('  This is a     string      with    many spaces ')
```

**Result**

```
This is a string with many spaces
```

Comment: Could I ask you one more thing?... In VBA I have IsNull() feature to check if something is Null is it the same in SQL?

Comment: In sql it's <expression> IS NULL. You can also use isnull(expresion, value-if-null)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FullTrim](@text nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN replace(@text, ' ', '')
END
```

...and then pass in all your fields concatenated together like:

```
SELECT dbo.FullTrim([tblLeadsResi.House Number] + [tblLeadsResi.Street] + ...) 
FROM tblLeadsResi
...
```